# Why is the content of this label not centered?

Tags: wpf, label, alignment

Consider the following xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DemoApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DemoApp.MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="100" FontSize="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0">A</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As shown in the image below, there is plenty of space within the label to accomodate the letter, yet it appears that the letter does not center as per the `VerticalContentAlignment`. What is the cause of this?

[image: Output of above code.]

Comment: Yes, thank you - it appears an issue with the GlyphOffset. How did you find that, I searched high and low but could not find anything remotely like that?

Comment: I had to deal with a similar issues related to fonts in the past :-) .

Answer (score 0):

I think VerticalContentAlignment has no problem.
Problem is that your Label is smaller than Font size.

```
<Label BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" FontSize="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0">A</Label>
```

Try this code.
I removed code "Height=100" and height is auto.

Comment: As expressed within the question, the label is plenty large enough for the font size, so that is not a solution. Thank you anyway.